# how to reuse a cell in tableview when different custom view add to the table as call

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, xcode5

1. ```
   cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

   if([ActivityStreamArray count]>[indexPath row])
   {
       GlobalMethod *LocalMethod = [ActivityStreamArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
       if (cell == nil)
       {
           cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier];
           if([[LocalMethod ActivityType] isEqualToString:@"photos"])
           {
               UIView *BackView=[[[NSBundle mainBundle]   loadNibNamed:@"ActivityExtendedDesign" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:12];
               CGRect TempBackRect=[BackView frame];
               TempBackRect.origin.x=0.0f;
               //TempBackRect.size.height+=ExtraHeightForImage;
               [BackView setFrame:TempBackRect];
               [cell addSubview:BackView];
           }
   ```

I am working on a web base application where I load content in `tableview`  from an extended `xiv`. This `xiv` contents views for my `tableview cell`. `Tableview` loads different content for different cell .The problem is that when I use `dequeueReusableCell`. The content did not show when scroll up.

Comment: Show us the code , which tried?

Comment: I am wondering about outer if block, is it implemented in that way, what are you trying to achieve here where you are checking your array's count > current indexpath's row?

Answer (score 0):

That's how, I think should be implemented as in your implementation above, only when your cell is nil, you are comparing LocalMethod's ActivityType and if it equals to "photos" then you are adding Backview to the uitablviewcell but when the cell is dequeued the it already contains Backview which is not what you want, if I am not mistaken you want to compare LocalMethod's ActivityType again and add other view if it is not equal to "photos".

```
cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
GlobalMethod *LocalMethod = [ActivityStreamArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

if (cell == nil)
{
    cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier];
}

if([[LocalMethod ActivityType] isEqualToString:@"photos"])
{
    UIView *BackView=[[[NSBundle mainBundle]   loadNibNamed:@"ActivityExtendedDesign" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:12];
    CGRect TempBackRect=[BackView frame];
    TempBackRect.origin.x=0.0f;
    //TempBackRect.size.height+=ExtraHeightForImage;
    [BackView setFrame:TempBackRect];
    [cell addSubview:BackView];  
}
```